# Precompile graphql using babel instead of webpack

Tags: webpack, graphql, babeljs, apollo, server-side-rendering

I already have working application with Apollo graphQl. And now I need to use SSR. I build backend node application with babel (without webpack).

In this case I need my application to build with babel as well as with webpack (hydration version for SSR)

In the no ssr version of application I had webpack loader:

```
  {
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
  },
```

Application worked fine with this loader.

Then I removed this loader from webpack, and added babel plugin:

```
  "plugins": [
    "import-graphql",
    "graphql-tag", 
    ....
```

But I have an error:

```
invariant.esm.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Argument of {
  cities {
    items {
      id
      logo
      name
      description
    }
  }
} passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document
```

I think, I have forgotten something, but I don't know what. Do you now, what should I do?

P.S The structure of code is:

[image]

where index.js imports as `import CITIES_QUERY from './query.gql';`